# Put a URL in a database via a php post method

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, post

I am trying to build a feedback option with php and MySql and I was wandering how I could stock the current URL on the database ?

Here's my post method (works fine for the feedback):

```
<form method="post" action="feedback.php" style="margin-top:-90px;">
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="radios" id="poor" value="poor" /><label for="poor">Poor</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radios" id="average" value="average" checked="checked" /><label for="average">Average</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radios" id="good" value="good" /><label for="good">Good</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </p>
</form>
```

And this is my function that put the information in the database:

```
<?php
try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', 'root', '');
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Erreur : ' .$e->getMessage());
}

if ($_POST['radios'] == 'good') {
    $bdd->exec('INSERT INTO feedback(id, url, avis) VALUES (\'\', \'\', \'Good\')');
} else if ($_POST['radios'] == 'average') {
    $bdd->exec('INSERT INTO feedback(id, url, avis) VALUES (\'\', \'\', \'Average\')');
} else {
    $bdd->exec('INSERT INTO feedback(id, url, avis) VALUES (\'\', \'\', \'Poor\')');
}

header('Location: Lexcelera_Translator.php');

?>
```

So how can I get the URL from the page where the form is and add it to my data base?

So just to avoid too many comment on the same post and make it easier to understand:

I now have `<input style="display:none;" name="url" value="<? echo 'http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]';?> "/> in my post form on my index.php` and I'm using

```
if ($_POST['radios'] == 'good') {
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $bdd->exec('INSERT INTO feedback(id, url, avis) VALUES ("", "'. mysql_real_escape_string($url) .'", "Good")');
}
```

to store it in my database like wlard suggested. But instead of the actual url, I got `<? echo 'http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]';?>` stored in MySql instead. Any idea? :(

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" value="your-url-here" name="url"/> ... $url = $_POST['url'];`

Answer (score 0):

put an invisible form field in your form like

```
<input style="display:none; name="url" value="<? echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>">
```

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that ^^ I'll try to include it in my php function. Thanks for you help!

Comment: So I now how can I put the value in my if/else function to ad the url to my database?

Comment: now your form includes the url of the page where the form was and you can simply save it to your database. Yes

Comment: Yes I understand that but I can't find the right syntax to put it in the VALUES part of my sql request... :/

Comment: `if ($_POST['radios'] == 'good') {
 $url = $_POST['url'];
    $bdd->exec('INSERT INTO feedback(id, url, avis) VALUES (\'\', $url, \'Good\')');
}`

Comment: `if ($_POST['radios'] == 'good') {  $url = $_POST['url'];     $bdd->exec('INSERT INTO feedback(id, url, avis) VALUES ("", "'. $url .'", "Good")'); }` sorry i didnt unescape the variable

Comment: Ok I wasn't putting the $url = $_POST['url'] in the right place, thanks.
But now in MySql it returns <? echo 'http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]'; ?> in the url part... Is there something wrong in the syntax in the form?

Comment: Don't use short tags `<?` put `<?php` also single quotes `'` escape variables. just put : `<?php echo 'http://'.SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]';?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the below code in your form tag

<input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];?> "/>

In your you function(db insertion function), you can take the value as $_POST['url']
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! (I just had to replace [HTTP_HOST] by ['HTTP_HOST'])

So it was just a syntax error after all ><

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thank you very much for your help! Here I post the final working version:

```
<form method="post" action="feedback.php" style="margin-top:-90px;">
        <p>
            <input type="radio" name="radios" id="poor" value="poor" /><label for="poor">Poor</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radios" id="average" value="average" checked="checked" /><label for="average">Average</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radios" id="good" value="good" /><label for="good">Good</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?> "/>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</p>
</form>
```

And the feedback.php:

```
<?php
try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', 'root', '');
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Erreur : ' .$e->getMessage());
}

if ($_POST['radios'] == 'good') {
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $bdd->exec('INSERT INTO feedback(id, url, avis) VALUES ("", "'. $url .'", "Good")');
} else if ($_POST['radios'] == 'average') {
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $bdd->exec('INSERT INTO feedback(id, url, avis) VALUES ("", "'. $url .'", "Average")');
} else {
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $bdd->exec('INSERT INTO feedback(id, url, avis) VALUES ("", "'. $url .'", "Poor")');
}

header('Location: index.php');

?>
```

Hope this can be useful to someone else :)